# 401 Unauthorized error.Failed to upgrade the authorization code into a credentials object

Tags: android, python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using oauth 2.0  with hybrid flow for google login https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow in my Android app. I get the one time authorization code into the android app and post it to my flask api through [postman](http://www.getpostman.com/). When I apply flow.step2_exchange to this one time auth code in the api it gives me **flow exchange error**. I have checked the auth code that arrives in the api is same as I got in my app. I cannot find the reason for the error.

My one time auth code looks like this :4/qXilPdy7xOVe5swCBlVRrxjuVu8zEzfcmidlooo7_ls

Code Snippet of my flask api:

```
# IMPORTS FOR THIS STEP
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets
from oauth2client.client import FlowExchangeError
import httplib2
import json
from flask import make_response
import requests


app = Flask(__name__)

CLIENT_ID = json.loads(
    open('client_secrets.json', 'r').read())['web']['client_id']
APPLICATION_NAME = "OAUTH_SERVER"
SCOPES = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
    # Add other requested scopes.
]

# Connect to Database and create database session
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///restaurantmenu.db')
Base.metadata.bind = engine

DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

@app.route('/gconnect', methods=['POST'])
def gconnect():
    request.get_data()
    code = request.data.decode('utf-8')
    print (code)

    # Upgrade the authorization code into a credentials object
    oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope = SCOPES)
    oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
    try:
        credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
        if credentials is None:
            print ("it is empty")
    except FlowExchangeError:
        response = make_response(
            json.dumps('Failed to upgrade the authorization code.'), 401)
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
        return response
```

My client_secret.json for the Api is named OAUTH_SERVER and it as follows:

```
{"web":
      {"client_id":"matches the one in console.apps.googleusercontent.com",
"project_id":"oauthapi",
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
"token_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
"auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
"client_secret":"###########",
"redirect_uris["http://localhost:5000/gconnect","http://localhost:5000/"],
"javascript_origins":["http://localhost:5000"]}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I see this is from the Udacity course - Authentication & Authorization. Please check if the login.html contains the proper data-clientid value. I had the same issue because upon copy forgot to change it with mine.

Comment: You are right this is from Udacity course but I have adapted this code for my android project. So I don't have a login.html. I login through my Android app sucessfully, then get the one time auth code and post it to api. My app and api have different client_secrets (supposed to be in case of app + api). The client_secret.json in my API is of web type (api).   I have checked the client id value. I am also posting the format of my client_secret JSON in my question, in case there is something wrong with it.

Comment: So to verify you have Android app that is client and Flask server backend (API). Why do they authenticate separately to google? I think that the Mobile app is the client that should wrap the logic in the "login.html" and your backend should have the client_secret. The mobile app should not have client_secret.

Comment: In udacity course a single client id, client secret has been used but I cannot do that in my case because web application and android application have different google_services json which cannot be exchanged. And also to get a one time auth code in android app I must provide the client ID of backend server in the app. Check this link  https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/backend-auth.

Comment: This is the link from google docs : https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

> `# Upgrade the authorization code into a credentials object
>   oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope = SCOPES)
>   oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
>   try:
>       credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
>       if credentials is None:
>           print ("it is empty")
>   except FlowExchangeError:`

to

`try:
        # Upgrade the authorization code into a credentials object
        oauth_flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', scope='')
        oauth_flow.redirect_uri = 'postmessage'
        credentials = oauth_flow.step2_exchange(code)
except FlowExchangeError:`

Comment: It still gives the same error. I took the first two lines out of 'try' to locate the line of code giving error.